# Why does having magnetic material in the middle of a stator help generate a current?

Tags: electromagnetism, wire, copper

It seems unintuitive to me why putting a stationary hunk or iron or neodynium in the middle of a copper coil generator would increase its conductivity, because the metal could act as its own conducting path and short paths along the copper wires and furthermore cancel out whatever opposite magnetic field is moving around it. So, why does it help?

Comment: It’s not about conductivity. Also, iron and neodymium are used for different reasons. Neodymium would be used to create a permanent magnet motor and (soft) iron is used in induction motors. Read up on motors in general, and induction in particular.

Comment: Reading up is why I have this question in the first place. I understand how a simple generator works, and I can make a generator easily from scrap metals (though not very efficiently). What I don't understand is why throwing a hunk of magnetic material in the middle of the design helps with that process.

Comment: It has to do with the magnetic field.  The magnetic field passes through the iron better than it passes through the air.  With your coil wrapped around the iron, more of field passes through the coil so you get more current.

Comment: Simple generator as in what type? Brushed PMDC? You need to read up on induction.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "magnetic circuit". Iron forms a "low reluctance" path (like low resistance for magnetic flux).  Whether that helps you or shorts out your flux paths depends on how well you design the "magnetic circuit". TL/DR you want to concentrate magnetic flux in the path which coils will pass through.

Comment: Maybe you are thinking about eddy currents and how they are much reduced by iron laminates?

Comment: @JRE "More field" doesn't quite make sense as far as I know. You can mask electric fields, but you can't mask magnetic fields, the magnetic field will pass through the air with the same velocity as it does iron though it would imply an additional force from the rotor. I could see that you obtain a greater current from having the iron bar, but why not just have more copper wire in that case?

Comment: More field because the magnetic force passes through the iron better than it passes through the air.  It concentrates the magnetic field.  More of it passes through the cpil, so more current.  Get out a magnet, iron filings, a sheet of paper and a piece of iron.  Compare the field lines with and without the iron involved.

Comment: More copper means more resistance= less current.

Comment: @JRE I can understand how there are "more" magnetic field lines, but those extra lines from the stationary piece of iron in the "stator" aren't moving relative to the copper, so how could they matter? Also, why doesn't any of the current leak into the iron/neodymium, why does it conveniently stay concentrated in the copper? There's a path of least resistance sure, but if you're talking a standard 60 hertz generator then the voltage would be great enough to overcome the impedance of air over a short distance.

Comment: You are mixing magnetic field lines and current.

Comment: The field lines come from the magnet, and the coils move with respect to the magnet.

Comment: @JRE Those those are pretty different things. The current is what I want generated from the magnetic field lines passing through the copper, you're just not doing a thorough job at explaining. We already agree that the field lines come from the magnet, that's not being debated. Depending on your frame of reference, either the magnet is moving or the copper is moving which ultimately doesn't matter. Relativity doesn't solve this dilemma alone. I could maybe see that having an extra magnet in the middle completes a stronger moving magnetic circuit, but how do they predict greater efficiency?

Comment: @JRE He want to know how a material will produce a lot of magnetic field. It is a pure physics question. I gave him a brief explanation in the comment of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The magnetic material doesn't increase the conductivity of the stator's coil.

The principle of any electrical machine is to use a rotating magnetic field to generate electrical coupling which allow for energy conversion. The stator's current is just a reaction to try counte-attack the induction in the stator's coil(lenz's law).

The reason why these materials are call "magnetic material" is that either they can generate a very large B field for relative small current or that their electron's spin are naturally aligned creating a noticeable B field.

Comment: See I already knew it generated a stronger magnetic field, hence the question, you haven't explained the actual mechanism for how. Luckily, a vector analysis approach let me quickly figure it out, but I haven't seen a reputable stackexchange member actually explain it. Most of the time when I consult electrical engineers, they have no idea how to explain the "why" behind any magnetic field interaction, they reiterate whatever they were tough and nothing more and it would be nice to see if a reputable stackexchabnge member would be able to explain it so that it was more palatable to the public.

Comment: Material will produce a lot of magnetic field if the molecular structure of the atoms allow the spins of the electrons to align themselves. It is in the realm of physics. An EE don't care about those mechanism because he only look at the global effect. To design an machine you don't need to use the principle by which magnetism is produce, you only need to know that certain material exhibit those characteristics

Comment: Again, I'm not disputing what allows a material to be magnetic, please don't put words in my mouth. I'm asking about how such a material is used to increase the efficiency of a generator.

Comment: @JohnJoe Here's one: Higher flux density => lower speed of wires is enough for certain voltage or as well shorter wires are enough if the speed is the same. The latter means less resistance and thus less losses. Lower speed means less friction, again less losses. In addition lower speed without changing mechanical dimensions mean lower AC frequency and thus less along frequency increasing losses such as magnetic hysteresis losses and skin effect resistance increase.

Answer (score 1):

Electricity is generated when a moving conductor cuts through lines of magnetic flux. A way to get a large amount of current is to have a lot of magnetic flux concentrated where the conductors are moving.

This diagram would be typical of an electric generator with a moving coil.
[image]

The grey material is iron. Think of this as a good "conductor" of magnetic flux. A complete magnetic circuit is formed driven by the N and S poles produced by the field coils. The flux runs from one pole through both sides of the yoke through the other pole and then across the rotor using the iron in the middle of the rotor.

This concentrates the field produced by the field coils into the area between the pole and the rotor and maximizes the amount of flux passed through by the armature conductors. The rotor iron in the middle of the coil helps this.

Iron is also an electrical conductor in order to reduce electrical generation and losses in the iron through eddy currents the iron is cut into thin slices (Laminations).

Answer (score 0):

If the coils were "air core", the ratio between mutual inductance and self-inductance would be considerably shifted. That is, there would be more flux leakage, (useless inductance). Greater flux leakage means more current is required to do the same work. Greater current means greater \$I^2R\$ losses.

On the other hand, an air core has virtually no core losses, so a designer may try to balance \$I^2R\$ losses against core losses to increases efficiency.